# What information does FIDO2 url contain and how can we decode it in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, webauthn, fido

In WWDC 2022 Apple launched GA for Passkeys which will enable in FIDO2 authentication, the next gen open standards based authentication mechanism to replace passwords.

On a Relying Party (RP) server supporting FIDO2 when a user registration is initiated, the browser generates a QR code to register a phone as platform authenticator.

I am trying to build an app which opens up a QR scanner view and I want to register for the FIDO credential by scanning the QR code generated by the browser. The parsed string is of the format - FIDO:/090409094349049349.......

What information does this FIDO:/090409094349049349....... url protocol contain relating to the RP? Also, is there a way to decode this in Swift to get that information in json or string format?

Since the camera app on iPhone is able to scan the QR and generate information like RP domain name and user being registered, I believe there should be a way to do this from a QR scanner inside an app as well. Or are these APIs private in nature only for usage of Camera app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Client Authenticator Protocol (CTAP) v2.2 hybrid flow link which is meant to bootstrap a Bluetooth connection between the device
reading the QR code and the host computer which shows it. This has formerly been known as "cloud assisted bluetooth low energy"
binding, or `cable` in short.

To decode one of these, lets take an example I created from the webauthn demo page [DEMO] when clicking on `Register`.

```
FIDO:/13086400838107303667332719012595115747821895775708323189557153075146383351399743589971313508078026948312026786722471666005727649643501784024544726574771401798171307406596245
```

The `FIDO:/` URI-scheme is registered with IANA at [IANA].

Next comes a base10-encoded string, which means that 7 bytes get encoded into 17 digits. It can be decoded for
instance with

```rust
     let x = input
         .chars()
         .collect::<Vec<char>>()
         .chunks(17)
         .flat_map(|c| {
             let s = c.iter().collect::<String>();
             let n = match s.len() {
                 3 => 1,
                 5 => 2,
                 8 => 3,
                 10 => 4,
                 13 => 5,
                 15 => 6,
                 17 => 7,
                 _ => panic!(),
             };
             s.parse::<u64>().unwrap().to_le_bytes().into_iter().take(n)
         })
         .collect::<Vec<u8>>();
```

This yields the byte string

```
a7 00 58 21 03 7e 2e f7 c6 5f a6 8e 15 ed 9b 9a 4c b7 22 34 cc ca 8f 9b 84 c7 62 52 d5 27 96 50 9b 31 88 ab 07 01 50 49 aa 2e f2 de 61 7e 4c
ba 2a e2 68 3d 3c ed 08 02 02 03 1a 64 05 fb 8e 04 f5 05 62 6d 63 06 f5
```

which is in fact a CBOR [CBOR, CBOR2] value that looks like

```
{
  0: h'037E2EF7C65FA68E15ED9B9A4CB72234CCCA8F9B84C76252D52796509B3188AB07', # compressed public key
  1: h'49AA2EF2DE617E4CBA2AE2683D3CED08',                                   # qr secret
  2: 2,                                                                     # num_known_domains
  3: 1678113678,                                                            # Timestamp: Mon Mar 06 2023 14:41:18 GMT+0000
  4: true,                                                                  # supports_linking 
  5: "mc",                                                                  # request_type -> CableRequestType::kMakeCredential
  6: true                                                                   # kWebAuthnNonDiscoverableMakeCredentialQRFlag enabled
}
```

To understand this map, we need to know the significance of the map keys, for which I couldn't obtain a normative source.
Thus, the truth lies in the code [CHROME].

Key `0` contains the compressed public key [BTC] of the relying party, in our case `https://webauthn.io`.

Key `1` contains the shared secret with which the device will proof that it read the QR code.

Key `2` contains the number of registered tunnel server domains.

Key `3` is the host unix time upon creation of the request, in our case Mon Mar 06 2023 14:41:18 GMT+0000

Key `4` tells us if the host computer showing the QR code supports device linking.

Key `5` is the request type of the operation, in this case `mc` which stands for Make Credential, i.e. we want to perform a device registration.
Note that this parameter is just a hint to the mobile device and not strictly necessary, as the QR code itself doesn't perform any Webauthn/CTAP operation,
it merely helps to avoid the Bluetooth Pairing of the two devices.

Key `6` declares that the call should be non-discoverable.

Further reading for WebAuthn [WEBAUTHN] and Client to Authenticator Protocol [CTAP].

--

[IANA] https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/fido

[DEMO] https://webauthn.io/

[CHROME] https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/50479218fc94681552b7ba2c526069141182a143/device/fido/cable/v2_handshake.cc#L441-L469 and https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/50479218fc94681552b7ba2c526069141182a143/device/fido/cable/v2_handshake.h#L107-L127

[CBOR] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8949.txt

[CBOR2] https://cbor.me/

[CTAP] https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.1-ps-20210615/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.1-ps-errata-20220621.html Note that this is only version 2.1. Our QR code will only
be specified in version 2.2 which is unfortunately not yet publicly available.

[WEBAUTHN] https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/

[BTC] https://btcinformation.org/en/developer-guide#public-key-formats

Comment: a bit of a long shot maybe, but do you know of a way to carry out the same process as you've described using Python? Thanks. :-)

Comment: Thank you, this is a great reference. Not your fault, of course, but the binary-to-ASCII encoding scheme here ("chunks of 17 decimal digits each encoding 7 little-endian bytes") is just about the most _awkward, inefficient, and error-prone_ binary encoding scheme I can imagine. It's far less efficient than (say) URL-safe base64 encoding (6 bytes→8 chars), or even simple hexlification (1 byte→2 chars). I wonder who chose it, and why ‍♂️.

Comment: @androidcontrol, using Python 3.2+ and the [`cbor`](https://pypi.org/project/cbor/) package, here's a horrible one-liner that'll decode the URI into the CBOR map: `import cbor, math; uri='FIDO:/...'; ns=uri.split('/')[-1]; bs=b''.join(int(n, 10).to_bytes(int(math.log2(10**len(n))//8), 'little') for n in (ns[ii: ii+17] for ii in range(0, len(ns), 17))); print(cbor.loads(b)) `

Comment: The CTAP 2.2 draft spec which includes the QR code definition is at: https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.2-rd-20230321/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.2-rd-20230321.html#hybrid-qr-initiated

Answer (score 1):

This is a FIDO protocol that is implemented as a system service/function and would not be useful to your app.

Comment: I am new to this concept and maybe I have not understood it completely. What I am interested in knowing is how does the Camera app get to know the RP domain name and name of user who is getting registered. What I understand is it identifies it as FIDO protocol and then advertises a BLE advertisement. How do we do so from inside an app having a QR scanner view?

Comment: If you want to support passkeys for sign in for your app, you need to call the system FIDO2 APIs.


Android: https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps

iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationplatformpublickeycredentialprovider

Comment: To expand on this, the QR code merely establishes a secure context between a device the user is using (e.g. laptop) and another device that actually holds the passkeys (phone). The actual WebAuthn/FIDO stuff (relying party, assertions, etc.) is relayed over a separate cloud service via a WebSocket tunnel that is established between the phone and laptop. This tunnel service and QR code handling is implemented by the platform (iOS/Android) and the client (web browser). So, as Tim said, you only need to use the auth APIs provided by the platform/browser, and they will take care of the rest.